# forward REGISTER message with kamailio

Tags: proxy, asterisk, sip, kamailio, registrar

There is kamailio on centos box and my scheme looks like this:

sip client ---> Kamailio ---> PBX (not asterisk)

and i need to know how i can just forward REGISTER and all MESSAGE from sip client via kamailio to PBX, except SUBSCRIBE.

i googled and i tried many times and i dont know what i am doing wrong

example  : **rewritehost** and **send**

there is a default kamailio.cfg and i am tring to add handle SIP registration method

```
if(is_method("REGISTER"))
 {
 send("udp:ip address:5060");
 };
```

and also i tried

```
rewritehost("ip address");
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check path module.

```
route[REGISTRAR] {
    if(!is_method("REGISTER"))
        return;
    add_path_received();
        route(DISPATCH);
}
```

I have created sample config, which works with Freeswitch and should work with any PBX which support PATH.

https://github.com/os11k/dispatcher/blob/master/kamailio.cfg

Comment: when i use your cfg, kamailio shows this error

 Process: 22523 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/kamailio start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

+ there is no loadmodule "dispatcher.so" in my default kamailio cfg

Comment: Check what is inside /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages
Make sure that you have DB module compiled. Additionaly you need to add your PBX to dispatcher table, if you want use completely my config.

Comment: firstly big thanks for the help

i also added dispatcher destination into the table but there are many errors in messages

**parse error in config file //etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 167, column 24: unknown command, missing loadmodule?**

Comment: Check what is on line 167 of your config file, this will give you a hint what module is missing, most probably you are missing db_mysql

Comment: thats not my cfg file, it is your kamailio cfg and it shows 43 errors on some lines

Comment: It is on your machine, than it is yours. I can't see it. Anyhow check logs and find out what module is missing if it is missing, use common sense.

Comment: ok thanks so much for help and last question to you, is dispatcher module only one way of this task ? can i just rewritehost REGISTER with this case ?

Comment: hello,

i have one question, can i change outbound source ip ( $si )

Comment: Why you need to change $si? And what you mean by "outbound"? $si - reference to IP source address of the message.

Comment: i will try to explain you, kamailio has two ip for example (eth0)1.1.1.1 and (eth1)2.2.2.2 , when register comes on 1.1.1.1 i want to forward it with/from 2.2.2.2

Comment: Ok, if you will send out using 2.2.2.2 then you should not change $si it will update automatically. 
Here some more details regarding multi-interfaces set-up: http://lists.sip-router.org/pipermail/sr-users/2016-June/093516.html

Comment: but when i send register on 1.1.1.1, kamailio automatic forward it using 1.1.1.1

Comment: Check link what I send there is description what you should do to make multi-interface set-up work properly. Check $fs pseudo-variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code block that will surely help you:

```
if (!is_method("REGISTER")) { save("location","0x02"); }
```

And before relay use, only for register message:

```
rewritehostport("192.168.1.90:5060");
```

Comment: Actually following code do not makes any sense:
`if (!is_method("REGISTER")) { save("location","0x02"); }`. It means that for any SIP method except register we should trigger save function, but save function works only with REGISTER messages, so it does nothing.

Comment: i think you didnt see below part of comment .. rewritehostport("192.168.1.90:5060");

Comment: I saw part below, but why you need `if (!is_method("REGISTER")) { save("location","0x02"); }` if it does nothing? It is very confusing. Additionally `rewritehostport("192.168.1.90:5060");` will not work too. It will just forward Register messages to "192.168.1.90:5060" server and without path module it will not work. So your answer is pretty much useless.

Comment: when the kamailio receive the register request add below code too                            if (is_method("REGISTER")) {
            add_path();
        } and you can set the destination by following line:     $du = "sip:192.168.1.102:5060";

Comment: Do a search on google for opensips register proxy.  They have an article on this which is relevant.  Syntax is very similar to kamailio.  I posted it as an answer but moderators who apparently do not understand anything about this subject deleted it